# Unable to instantiate the smart contract

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, ibm-blockchain, ibp-vscode-extension

I am following the tutorial to develop a Hyperledger Fabric smart contract and application using IBM Blockchain Platform. I am in step A3.5 In the Fabric Environments view, click "Smart Contracts" -> "Instantiated" -> "+ Instantiate". When I do, I get the following error:

```
env: node: No such file or directory
The terminal process terminated with exit code: 127
```

Comment: Hi there, what tutorial are you following?

Comment: The one in the IBM blockchain platform VS code extension

Comment: looks like you don't have node available on your path. I would recommend using `nvm` from https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm to get node available on your terminal path.